# Which to use: "have been" or "have become"?

Tags: present-continuous

> Since the time I spent in LA, **I've been** a huge Lakers fan.

or

> Since the time I spent in LA, **I've become** a huge Lakers fan.

Also, would it be okay if I replaced the word 'time' with 'years'?

Comment: Both imply that you are no longer in LA, and the second implies that you did not become a Lakers fan until after you left.

Comment: Both versions are a bit "odd" with *since*, which usually references a *specific **point** in time*, not some extended period (apart from anything else, your audience would have no idea whether you became a Lakers fan *when* you went to LA, *after* you'd spent time in LA, or *during* the time you were there). It might be clearer to rephrase as, say, ***After spending time** in LA...*, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that both sound a bit odd, though they are grammatically correct.

The first part could be rephrased to "Since I spent time in LA", which would sound more natural.

"I've been a huge Lakers fan" gives the idea that you became a fan almost immediately after spending time in LA.

"I've become a huge Lakers fan" gives the idea of a process, which began after spending time in LA, and you *eventually* considered yourself a fan.

Comment: Your version of the sentence works better because, in this structure, **since** can mean **because**. "Because I spent time in LA, I've become a huge Lakers fan". This eliminates the illogical temporal link which implies that you didn't start becoming a fan until after you left.